# How to hide child of products if anyone has quantity 0 or below 0?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

i want to hide swatches of configurable products which has 0 quantity and i want to use the best approach possible is there any?

[image]

**how to do that any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Check `Show out of stock product` setting under `Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory`
Set `Show out of stock product` to `No`.
And then clear System Cache.

See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/catalog/inventory.html for more details.

Comment: its already set to NO and it still shows child products with 0 quantity

Comment: @IZANOVA try disabling third party modules and theme and see if the same behavior persists.